# git pull subtree deletes everything

Tags: git, git-subtree

I'm trying to take advantage of the subtree feature in git where I can have a repo that reference an other repo and thus appears to have all the files of both repos.  I have read a couple of intros [**here**](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html) and [**here**](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging) and have tried to follow them.

So I have two repos in git hub.  I do this

```
git checkout testBranchA
git pull origin testBranchA
git remote add external git@github.com:reharik/repoB
git fetch external
git checkout -b external external/testBranchB
git read-tree --prefix=src/ -u external
git commit -m "added subtree"
```

so now I look at my file sys and I see all the files from both repos and everything is great.  Then I do

```
git pull -s subtree external testBranchB
```

and it seems that everything in both local repos is deleted.  infact first it does

```
removing src/...
```

on all files, then it seems to do a merge where you see all the files with red and green +'s and -'s, then it does

```
delete mode 100644 src/...
```

for all files

So i'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but clearly it's something.

Any help would be appreciated

=== edit sorry to keep changing the commands, I'm a bit fried at this point but I think this is the syntax I'm using

Comment: I had the same problem. I later found out that it was when I added the subtree (`git subtree add`), I forgot to use `--prefix`. It should have warned me, just as what `git subtree pull` does, but it didn't. Once I redo it with correct `--prefix` when `add`, the later `pull`s work out fine.

Answer (score 0):

That last `git pull -s subtree ...` command does not seem right, since it is not taking into consideration the location of the subtree. As it is it will try to smash together both trees at the root level, which could be the cause of the files being deleted.

Try instead:

```
git pull -s recursive -X subtree=src/ external testBranchB
```